# Problems compiling GnuPlot on Windows 8.1 using the .exe

Tags: windows, gnuplot

System info: Windows 8.1
Intel processor
16.0 GB of Ram
x64-based OS

I have downloaded GnuPlot version 5.0.0 and 5.0.1 from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/

I have tried downloading via the .exe installer and the .tar.gz folder methods of the x64 based files. Both have ended in the program being unable to run on my system.

The runtime error was as follows:
"gnuplot createprocess failed code 267 the directory name is invalid"

I have also tried installing and running 5.0.0 GnuPlot through Cygwin environment; this also didn't work.

Any suggestions? or things that I am not doing?

Comment: I can't follow you. Just download the file http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.1/gp501-win64-mingw.zip/download and unpack it. Then double-click wgnuplot.exe

Comment: I am just getting started with this program, are there any tutorials and documentation so that I can learn this program as fast as possible!